# Is the term "emergence" used differently by physicists compared to how they are used in philosophy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is the term "emergence" used differently by physicists compared to how they are used in philosophy?

In the video below, physicists are talking about the emergence of space, but it seems that some of the viewers realized that the term "emergence" is used differently than how it is typically used by philosophers.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XXek3poC6E

Here's a quote:

> I think you are correct in your assumption of a somewhat different
>   definition for emergence used by physicists. We might think that
>   emergence means the way in which an increasingly complex and
>   unpredictable reality "emerges" from a series of smaller, less complex
>   components within the reality thus created. (The way "life"  or even
>   consciousness emerges from "non-living" cellular components). But from
>   what I can gather, physicists talk about the emergence of lower
>   dimensional realities from higher ones. For example, Klee Irwin is
>   doing some very interesting work in simulation theory that posits our
>   3D reality "emerges" from a higher dimension crystal in the same way
>   that a 2D shadow emerges from a 3D form.

Is this the case and could you explain why it is the case so that a layman like me who doesn't know much about quantum physics can understand?

Comment: Most specialties have used vocabulary in ways that are specific to that specialty. This applies from architecture to zoology, with physics and philosophy just being two things starting with ‘ph’.

Comment: Klee Irwin is known to be a fraudster (he's been ordered to pay millions in damages for false advertising and unfair business practices resulting from one of the alternative medicine companies he started before abruptly pivoting to theoretical "physics"), and there's a reason he's not receiving any public funding: https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Klee_Irwin.